# Column names have moved in attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I've joined an excel spreadsheet to one of my point shapefile. After performing the join, I can see that the names of the columns have not been set as the name in the attribute table column; instead the names are one row below as shown in the picture. Any insight on how I could fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the box first row contains column names when importing the excel file?

Comment: No but I was looking for it. Could you tell me where can I find it?

Comment: My spreadsheet is not a CSV, because when I transform it into a CSV, all attributes are in one row all packed together, I don't know why

Comment: In spreadsheet layers plugin there is a box right below filename, sheet and layername where you can set the `lines to ignore` and `header at first line`.